# Oracle SQL: Select specific string from CLOB field

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table where one of the fields is a CLOB, it stores a error message information.

The field CLOB as the following content:

```
oracle.retail.sim.common.core.SimServerException: Error processing message! [Inbound: true, MessageType: ItemLocCre, BusinessId: 1101505002]
    at oracle.retail.sim.service.mps.SimMessageCommand.buildException(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.retail.sim.service.mps.SimMessageProcessCommand.doExecute(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.retail.sim.common.core.Command.execute(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor273.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused by: oracle.retail.sim.common.core.SimServerException: Item not found for Id: 1101505002
    at oracle.retail.sim.server.integration.consumer.itemloc.ItemLocConsumer.buildItemNotFoundException(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.retail.sim.server.integration.consumer.itemloc.ItemLocCreateConsumer.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.retail.sim.server.integration.consumer.itemloc.ItemLocCreateConsumer.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.retail.sim.server.integration.consumer.SimMessageConsumerFactory.consume(Unknown Source)
    ... 56 more
```

Im trying to display the result of the clob directly in the PL/SQL output, so im using the following query:

```
select id, dbms_lob.substr(message_error, 4000, 1) AS ERROR_MESSAGE
  from THE_TABLE;
```

What i pretend is to select only the line that contains the 'Caused by..' string. What i need is to extract only the following error message:

```
Item not found for Id: 1101505002
```

It is possible to do so whith only a select statement?

Thanks in advance,
Best regards,

Comment: Show us your stored procedure

Comment: Hello, Is not a procedure, is just a simple query that will be used for reporting proposes.

Comment: So where does the "PL/SQL output" come from if you don't have a stored procedure?

Comment: Hello, it comes directly when doing the select statement in plsql developer. What i need is The function to retrieve only The sentence containing The string causes By. Mathguy answers works as expected. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query (substitute your actual table and column names) will extract one line of text, from the words `Caused by` to the end of that line. It doesn't matter if the line of text begins with `Caused by` - you will only get everything from those words to the end of the line.

If you need a shorter sub-string from that, you will need to explain in more detail how it can be "recognized" - how do you decide what can be left out and what must be returned. How is that delimited?

```
select regexp_substr(message, 'Caused by:.*) as caused_line
from   test_data;
```

(Note that by default the wildcard character `.` does **not** match the end-of-line in regular expressions in Oracle.)

Comment: Hello,
This did work i used the following in order to make the clob visible directly in the output without the need to open all the clob file:

`dbms_lob.substr(regexp_substr(message_error, 'Caused by:.*'), 4000, 1) AS error_message`

Thanks, i will not try to find a way to remove the **Caused by:** from the output.